# Is it possible to implement "Reviews" 'for the store' instead of 'for products'

Tags: layout, customer

I have recently started to use Magento-CE. I would to implement "Reviews" at the website/store level , not at the product level. 
I would like to create a CMS page with the form and the 
list of all reviews but don't know what XML code to put there. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: You have to create custom module with front router. Create a backend grid for review. Create custom functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'path of least resistance' for this is to re-use the core review functionality. This way you do not need to code your own entire review system.

You can create a 'not visible individually' product, and attach your review(s) to this product. This can then also work for multiple stores, each having their own 'review product'

This way you can re-use most, or all core review functionality. No need to re-invent the wheel ;)

You can take it a bit further and add in your own admin display grid to list the review attached to this product, thus visually separating the reviews from the product area in admin as well. This should be easy enough by replicating the core review grid to your own module, and dropping/hiding the Product Name and Product SKU grid columns from the display as well.

As for how to get the review form into the cms page, easy:

In the cms page 'Design' tab, in the 'Layout Update XML' you can place this:

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="review/form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form"></block>
</reference>
```

This will inject the form into your page.
The issue is that the core block `Mage_Review_Block_Form::getAction()` method is expecting a productId from the request object

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('id', false);
```

So what you'd need to do is (in your own module) create a new Block that extends (not rewrite, just extend) the core block `Mage_Review_Block_Form` and extend the getAction() method to load in your 'special reviews product' id.

Thus, once you have your own block you can have the method as such:

```
public function getAction()
    {
        $productId = $this->getProductId()
        return Mage::getUrl('review/product/post', array('id' => $productId));
    }
```

and adjust your block in the layout directive as such:

```
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="YOUR_NAMESPACE_MODULE/form" name="cms.product.review.form" as="cms_review_form">
<action method="setProductId"><id>YOUR PRODUCT ID</id></action>
</block>
        </reference>
```

which will then pass the required productId to your cms based review form.

Note: The above is not a complete solution, there will be more to extend, potentially you'd have to also use a more custom template.phtml (which you can set via the _construct, or via the block directive), and also potentially have to extend some more functions.

All in all, this would hopefully give you some ideas, or a way forward to your final solution.

Good luck